# Angular 4 kendo numerictextbox Percentage issue

Tags: angular5, kendonumerictextbox

If I enter 5 I want to display 5% but it is rendering as 500%. How can I display?

```
<kendo-numerictextbox [decimals]="2" [format]="'p'" [(ngModel)]="Percentage"></kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<kendo-numerictextbox [decimals]="2" [format]="'# \\%'" [(ngModel)]="Percentage"></kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Comment: If this solved your problem accept this as the answer.